# Plot ROC curve in R with the PRROC package

Tags: r, logistic, data-visualization, model, roc

After many hours of research, trial and error and frustration I hope someone here will be able to guide me in the right direction. I am fairly new to R and statistics and can not wrap my hand about the workings of the **roc.curve()** function of the **PRROC package in R**.
**My goal is to plot a ROC curve** in the standard fashion provided by the PRROC package like this:

[Picture: Example ROC curve](https://ibb.co/BPYYzG8)

I now want to plot the ROC curve for the fitted logistic regression model with the testdata.
**My problem is, that I only get AUC values either 1 or 0** according to the order I put in my data in the curve is rectangluar.

Can someone see my mistake? **Any help is greatly appreciated.**

[PRROC Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PRROC/vignettes/PRROC.pdf)

```
library(PRROC)

# Split set
# Subset
# Logistic regression
# predict test-data
# ROC curve plot NOT WORKING
x<-c(fg_data,bg_data)
y<-c(rep(1,length(fg_data)),rep(0,length(bg_data)))

roc<-roc.curve(scores.class0 = x, weights.class0 = y, curve = TRUE)
plot(roc)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok let's do it in one way, according to the vignette (?roc.curve):

> scores.class0: the classification scores of i) all data points or ii)
>             only the data points belonging to the positive class.
>
> ```
>       In the first case, scores.class1 should not be assigned an
>       explicit value, but left at the default
>       (scores.class1=scores.class0).  In addition, weights.class0
>       needs to contain the class labels of the data points (1 for
>       positive class, 0 for negative class) or the soft-labels for
>       the positive class, i.e., the probability for each data point
>       to belong to the positive class.  Accordingly, weights.class1
>       should be left at the default value (1-weights.class0).
> ```

So we provide the probability of being positive class, and a weights that is as long as your testset:

```
glm.probs.test <- predict(glm.fit,testset ,type = "response")
```

Now we need a weight that is 1 if positive, 0 if negative class in the actual label, by default your factors are numerically coded as 1 and 2, so -1 gives 0,1:

```
wt1 <- as.numeric(testset$true_value)-1
```

Then plot:

```
roc = roc.curve(scores.class0=glm.probs.test,weights.class0=wt1,curve=TRUE)
plot(roc)
```